# Maven copies subfolder xhtml files to main folder

Tags: subdirectory

excerpt of my project structure: The WebContent folder contains:

```
some.xhmtl
| secured
    someother.xhtml
```

When I run Maven clean install from eclipse, the files created in the root folder of target (and in the war) are like that:

```
-some.xhmtl
-someother.xhtml
| secured
    -someother.xhtml
```

someother.xhtml is duplicated in the ROOT folder.

How can I avoid this?

This is how I have configured the war plugin in pom.xml:

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-war</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>war</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <webXml>path/to/web.xml</webXml>
                        <webResources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>\WebContent\</directory>
                            </resource>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>\WebContent\secured\</directory>
                            </resource>
                        </webResources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

After dealing with Maven war-plugin (basics) another few hours, I found the solution myself:

```
                        <resource>
                            <directory>\WebContent\secured\</directory>
                        </resource>
```

This had to be removed. Maven will take the subfolders of

```
                        <resource>
                            <directory>\WebContent\</directory>
                        </resource>
```

into the war anyhow. Putting the subfolder as resource just tells Maven to put all files there to the root folder (i.e. "treat subfolder as a main source folder and put all content to the main target folder")